# Receipt Printer - print from webpage

Tags: html, firefox, printing, network-printers

I have a receipt Printer and it connected to Serial COM1 on to my comuter.

I am trying to print a receipt from the webpage and when it print... it just a blank without any text. (Blank receipt!).  It work fine on IE8 but not working on Firefox 3.6

I have an Epson TM-T88II Printer and using "Generic / Text" driver on Windows 7.

What is the solution to this?

HTML code of receipt:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>Company Name</div>
        <div>Customer Name</div>
        <div>Order No</div>
        <div>1 x Item</div>
        <div>1 x Item</div>
        <div>1 x Item</div>
        <div>12.00</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bu49K/

Comment: If you have a printer problem, you're asking in the wrong place (unless you hacked the printer or wrote its drivers). That said, try to print other pages, try to copy the receipt to another program (like Word) and print that, or try taking a screen shot.

Comment: There is no problem printing on the notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a solution: Have a look at [jQPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint)

EDIT:

Have a look at jQuery or other javascript plugins that do this, try jQPrint if it's still supported or try searching if the link is broken. I realise this is an old answer and they type of answer that is no longer permitted. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Work fine on IE but not firefox?

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to load a java applet, jzebra can print directly to the Epsom TM series thermal printers to COM1 port using the Generic Text driver as you've described.

https://github.com/qzind/qz-print

The problem you are encountering is not uncommon.  Generic/Text bypasses the PostScript (2D) capabilities of the Epson print driver.

If using Generic/Text, Epson uses the ESC/P programming language.  You will find many tutorials on the internet for printing in this format, and jzebra has more information about this style of "RAW" printing here:

https://github.com/qzind/qz-print/wiki/Raw-Printing

**Edit:**

To get this working, simply setup your receipt printer as the default printer and rename it as "zebra":

[image]

Then simply download the [qz-print](https://github.com/qzind/qz-print/) library, put the jar file in the project directory and hey presto:

```
<input type=button onClick="print()" value="Print">
<applet id="qz" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" archive="./qz-print.jar" width="100" height="100">
      <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>

<script>
      function print() {
       qz.append("PRINTED USING JZEBRA\n");
       qz.print();
      }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is very old question, but it is still difficult to find a good solution. I used to use QZ Tray solution (as Tres Finocchiaro has described), but now I think I've found a better one that provides full control over the process:

1. Register custom protocol (like "https", "http", "mailto") named, for instance, "print". It is done using registry editor in Windows.
2. Write a custom protocol handing application which will be automatically executed by Windows when somebody is going to open a link like "print://any/parameters/go/here".
3. Implement printing in your application. I'm using C# and built-in PrintDocument class, so it is extremely simple.

Now I can just create a link with href like "print://invoice/1234" and then parse this URI in your application and print whatever you need. It works even from a command line.

[image: The printing result photo]

[Here](http://sikorsky.pro/en/blog/how-to-print-from-a-web-page-to-a-pos-printer) you can get more information.