# stop printing after done printing div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

i want to stop printing when div content is done printing.The problem is that if the content has little content it appears the rest of the page blank.I want to cut the page after the content is done printing.I am using a receipt printer.

```
 function Popup(data) 
{   
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'day', 'height=300,width=400');
    mywindow.height
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"   />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Here's a question that addresses receipt printers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232531/receipt-printer-print-from-webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can define css to create page break after a element.

```
@media print
{
  .some_element {page-break-after:always;}
}
```

See reference here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: I tried this but with id not class and still the same.The paper is not cut after the div

Comment: hy did you find solution?

Comment: Same problem here, could anyone find a Java Script solution?